# Swift public var with default value and run didSet for that default value

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I have my Swift class as the simple code below:

```
class FavoriteView: UIView {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        // init something
    }

    // MY PROBLEM IS HERE
    var favoriteCount: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            // update the view
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is whenever the `favoriteCount` is set to a new value, the code in `didSet` is run.

It runs well. But the problem is that code (in `didSet`) is not run for the very first time. I mean when a new `FavoriteView` instance is initialized, I assume it to run also, but it's not.

Is there any way to run that code (in `didSet`) for the first time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

`didSet` observer not invoked with default values, as well as it not invoked when you setting up properties in `init` methods (due to `self` not initialized yet). You may write separated method `updateView` and invoke it in `init` method **and** in `didSet` observer.

```
private func commonInit() {
    updateView()
    // init something
}

// MY PROBLEM IS HERE
var favoriteCount: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}

func updateView() {
    //code that you wanted to place in observer
}
```